# Tucking in a shirt with tzitzis

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, how-to

I wear white dress shirts everyday, tucked into my pants. I've always tucked in the shirt and then pulled the tzitzis out so that they hang out from my beltline. However, this seems to make the shirt come untucked easily. Any tips?